# JavaScript+PHP: Преобразование PHP-кода в HTML-комментарий

Tags: php, javascript, html

Задача: вставить c помощью JS и PHP фрагмент HTML-кода. Сделать это в принципе можно, примеры есть, но у меня не получилось это сделать потому, что JavaScript преобразует `<?`, с которых начинается PHP-код, в HTML-комментарий. Т. е. код

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML  = "<?php $a=1; echo a; ?>";
```

вставит

```
<!--?php $a=1; echo a; ?-->
```

В результате экспериментов я также выяснил, что достаточно пары `<?` и `>`, чтобы *JavaScript* расценил это как комментарий. Экранирование не помогает.

Что можно сделать?

Comment: а зачем вам php код на стороне клиента?

Comment: через него легче вставлять HTML-код из внешних файлов, чем на чистом JS и jQuery. Вероятно и в быстродействии выигрыш будет.

Comment: он просто не будет исполняться на стороне клиента. это серверный язык. Он должен быть выполнен до загрузки страницы. Вызывайте через ajax свой скрипт

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас буду узнавать, как это делать. Спасибо за совет!

Comment: С помощью ajax, конечно же

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP код всегда выполняется на стороне сервера. Для вставки результата выполнения PHP скрипта на стороне клиента нужен XMLHttpRequest.
JavaScript:

```
// 1. Создаём новый объект XMLHttpRequest
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// 2. Конфигурируем его: GET-запрос на URL 'get_data.php'
xhr.open('GET', 'get_data.php', false);

// 3. Отсылаем запрос
xhr.send();

// 4. Если код ответа сервера не 200, то это ошибка
if (xhr.status != 200) {
  // обработать ошибку
  alert( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText ); // пример вывода: 404: Not Found
} else {
  // вывести результат
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML  = xhr.responseText;
}
```

Php код на серверной стороне (get_data.php)

```
<?php
$a = 1;
echo $a;
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо! Благодаря тому, что Вы всё детально объяснили, у меня не только всё сразу заработало, но я реально понял, что делаю!

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML  = "&#060;? $a=1; echo a; ?&#062;";
```