# JS&PHP: можно ли передать значение переменной через XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: php, javascript

В [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542741/javascriptphp-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-php-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-html-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9) вопросе я узнал, как вставить HTML-код с помощью JavaScript и PHP (не будем углубляться в том, зачем это). Решением было использование `XMLHttpRequest`. А теперь вопрос: а можно ли этим же способом не просто вставить содержимое PHP-документа (например, `insert.php`), а ещё и передать значение переменной тому скрипту, что в `insert.php`?

По порядку:

1. Выполняем JS-скрипт, в котором переменная (назовём её стандартно - `X` "икс") принимает те или иные целочисленные значения.
2. Передаём значение `X` в `insert.php`. Как это сделать, я и хочу спросить, а сам покажу примерное содержание `insert.php`:

.

```
$_GET($X); // принимаем переменную из js-скрипта

switch($X) {
    case 1: 
        echo "<b>One</b>";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "<b>Two</b>";
        break;
}
```

JS-скрипт выполняется как при первой загрузке страницы, так и при изменении ширины окна (это я уже обеспечил).

---

Обновление: добавил свою неудачную попытку сделать как в предложенной [ссылке](http://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-forms). У меня в браузере вообще нет ничего при запуске этого скрипта.

JS:

.

```
var url = "SubIndex.php";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params = 'name=' + encodeURIComponent(name) +
    '&surname=' + encodeURIComponent(surname);

xhr.open("GET", url+"?"+ params, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(xhr .readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.send();
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
if (isset($name)) echo $name;
else echo "фэил";
?>
```

Comment: А вы пробовали читать какие-то стать про XMLHttpRequest? Искать свой вопрос в поисковике? Элементарные же вещи спрашиваете. http://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-forms

Comment: Конечно, и не только на русском читал. Попытки применить к своему случаю те примеры, которые я видел, пока не привели к положительному результату. Кстати, этот вопрос, что я задал, на момент написания комментария на 3-ем месте в поисковике был, если ввести "XMLHttpRequest передать переменную" :)

Comment: И по ссылке, которую я привёл в комментарии вы не нашли ответа на свой вопрос? Возможно, дело в том, что вы не совсем правильно формулируйте вопрос. Вам ведь нужно не переменную передать на сервер, а её значение. А что такое значение переменной в данном контексте? Это данные. По запросу "XMLHttpRequest передать данные" находится огромное количество релевантной информации.

Comment: То, что Вы привели в ссылке, тоже пробовал (далал почти 1 в 1). Вообще никакой реакции, даже сообщение о неудачной попытке не всплывает. Сейчас добавлю свою попытку в вопрос.

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста как в итоге передать параметы самому себе (в рамках одной страницы) из блока js в блок php $_GET или $_POST через XMLHttpRequest в консоли вижу что запросы уходят, но массивы $_GET $_POST пустые, в ответе при xhr.open xhr.onreadystatechange идет (xhr.responseText) полный код страницы и все а после xhr.send(); пусто - т.е. запрос уходит вникуда хотя прописываю полный путь к текущей странице

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не отрабатывает из за неопределённых переменных. Добавьте

```
var name = "123";
var surname = "123";
```

и будет Вам счастье.

Comment: Благодарю! Я думал, они в params и определены...